# Suppress static block

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, powermockito

**Programming Language : Java

Testing tool         : powermockito,Junit**

I have a static block in my code. I am using that code particle as several reference. While during integration testing (using powermockito) I mocked a `getWebDetails()` method in the below example. The method for mocking (`getWebDetails`) is also getting called from the static block in my program, so it excecutes before my test gets excecuted and returns a null value. I need to assign values to xml contents during my testing.

```
class test1{
    private static String xmlcontents;

    static {
        xmlcontents= ServiceUtils.getWebDetails();
    }

    public static String getWebDetails() throws Exception{
        url = test2.getURL();
        return url;
    }
}
```

Nota bene (please note): I tried using @SuppressStaticInitializationFor("test1"), but it suppresses all the static methods inside the class.

Can anyone help me? Any help will be highly appreciable..